# Why do Red Hat provide builds compiled with different Java compiler versions?

Tags: java, maven

Why do Red Hat provide builds of the same source code compiled with different Java compiler versions?

Particularly hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:
https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/

If there is value in this, why are there not builds of the same source code in Maven Central for different compiler versions?

Maven Central only has 1 final build:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/

Comment: I personally always use the OpenJDK repository.

Comment: Where did you see any mention of different compiler versions? I can't find any such reference in the link that you provided.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the MANIFEST.MF in the compiled JARs in the META-INF folder says the compiler version.

Comment: @markspace Can you link to it?

Comment: It would be nice to know why my question was down voted. It's a bit unfair getting it without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: There is a difference between those jar files. The MANIFEST has been changed to contain different information for OSGi...What I find really bad is that RedHat seemed to use the same coordinates except the version which will be likely overseen but enhancing the OSGi dependencies might be the reason for doing so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know it is RedHat support model.

- Maven Central - is upstream OpenSource version while
- RedHat version is supported by RedHat.

As you can see RedHat has version as "1.0.0.Final-redhat-2", so who pays for support will get it from RedHat if this version is in use, but upstream OpenSource version is not supported by RedHat.

Answer (score 1):

The real answers to both of these questions is .... ask the people who manage these things.  The real reasons probably include pragmatic / business reasons.

First of all, there is a definite advantage for having JAR files that are built with older Java tool chains.  For example, a Java 7 platform won't run JARs build for Java 8 or later because of the classfile version number, and in some cases because of Java API dependencies.  So what Redhat is doing is better for people (i.e. **paying customers**) who *need* to build to run on older versions of Java ... to a point.

On the other hand ... Maven Central is a community effort.  Artifacts are built and published by the developers themselves (or sometimes by third parties); see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html:

- Many developers have no interest in supporting old Java platforms.
- Some developers think is it is a bad idea to support old Java platforms.  Running code on old unsupported versions of Java (version 7 and earlier) is bad for security, unless you take steps to mitigate this.

Furthermore, neither Maven POM files or Maven Central have a good way to flag Java version compatibility or to identify artifacts by their Java build platform.  (Correct me if I am wrong about this ....)

In an ideal world, "someone" would do something about this.  In practice ... see the bullet points above.

Comment: hibernate-jpa-2.1-api has a package built with an older Java version on Maven Central and packages built with 2 newer Java versions on Red Hat repository. You answer likely applies to other packages which are the opposite however. Good information, thanks